How do I pretty print the source code of functions contained in a class instance's attributes?
I would like to use rich to pretty print a Python class like so:
from dataclasses import dataclass
import inspect
from typing import Any, Callable
from rich import print as rprint
import rich.repr
from rich.syntax import Syntax


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    fs: list[Callable[..., Any]]

    def __rich_repr__(self) -> rich.repr.Result:
        for f in self.fs:
            yield (
                f.__name__,
                rprint(
                    Syntax(
                        inspect.getsource(f), lexer="python", theme="lightbulb"
                    ),
                ),
            )


def g(x: int, y: str) -> list[str]:
    return [y] * x


def h(y: str, zs: list[str]) -> str:
    return " ".join([y + z for z in zs])


my_class = MyClass([g, h])

rprint(my_class)

Which produces as output, roughly:
def g(x: int, y: str) -> list[str]:                                                                                
    return [y] * x                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                   
def h(y: str, zs: list[str]) -> str:                                                                               
    return " ".join([y + z for z in zs])                                                                           
                                                                                                                   
MyClass(g=None, h=None)

How do I get rich to pretty print the source strings of the functions? I figured that Pretty has something to do with it, but couldn't quite get it to work.
EDIT: some more experimentation suggests that Syntax is also relevant. I have updated my example code to show something that prints something more like what I'd like, but it's not there yet. Essentially, what's happening is that rprint outputs the source code as I'd like, but the rich representation of MyClass ends up getting Nones as the result of the call to rprint. So rprint is clearly not the right function to use there.

The relevant documentation is under "Console Protocol".
from dataclasses import dataclass
import inspect
from typing import Any, Callable
from rich import print as rprint
from rich.console import Console, ConsoleOptions, Group, RenderResult
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich.syntax import Syntax
from rich.text import Text


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    fs: list[Callable[..., Any]]

    def __rich_console__(
        self, console: Console, options: ConsoleOptions
    ) -> RenderResult:
        func_sources = []
        for f in self.fs:
            func_sources.append(
                Syntax(
                    inspect.getsource(f),
                    lexer="python",
                    theme="lightbulb",
                )
            )

        panels = Panel(
            Group(*func_sources),
            title=Text(self.__class__.__name__, style="bold"),
            title_align="left",
            expand=False,
        )
        yield panels


def g(x: int, y: str) -> list[str]:
    return [y] * x


def h(y: str, zs: list[str]) -> str:
    return " ".join([y + z for z in zs])


my_class = MyClass([g, h])

rprint(my_class)

Produces roughly as output:
╭─ MyClass ────────────────────────────────╮
│ def g(x: int, y: str) -> list[str]:      │
│     return [y] * x                       │
│                                          │
│ def h(y: str, zs: list[str]) -> str:     │
│     return " ".join([y + z for z in zs]) │
│                                          │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────╯

